# Possible to rewrite base URL vs one with short ID added in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I want to support https://example.com/7_8jkil (ie. a shortid) be handled by one page in my firebase app. I currently have it working as https://example.com/room/7_8jkil

I am unsure if its even possible given the pattern matching in Firebase rewrites.

Here is my current rewrite code:

```
    "rewrites": [
  {
   "source": "/room/**",
   "destination": "/room.html"
  },
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough I tried the following and its seems to work!

```
    "rewrites": [
  {
   "source": "/**",
   "destination": "/room.html"
  },
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
```